# is it possible to call an entity from view ( php template ) in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6

I got a dynamic content in layout which is takes vales from database. What is the best way to achieve this rather than passing values from controller.

Is it possible to call an entity from view? I am using php template.

Comment: Pass entities to the controller, then use getters in your view to retrieve whatever values you need. If this is not dynamic enough, then you may want to use AJAX.

Comment: [you can Write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: please consider this case am uploading site logo from admin area , logo path is saved in database. To use this logo in layout i have to pass it from every controller ?

Answer (score 2):

there's no point in a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) context to call a model entity without the use of a controller, at least you can fetch the updated content using a ajax call to a controller which returns a [JsonResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html) to avoid the page refresh

Comment: please consider this case am uploading site logo from admin area , logo path is saved  in database. To use this logo in layout i have to pass it from every controller ?

Comment: the best thing you can do is use a controller as entry point for the logo contextual to the current system state

i.e. controller returns image response (header content type set to the image mime) at endpoint http://websi.te/logo.png

then in your template you can use the always known path /logo.png

this is also used for [mail tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible via the twig extension.

Register a twig extension
[TWIG EXTENSION](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Pass to __constructor() - @doctrine service

`services.yml`

```
   my.twig.extension:
      class: twig\namespace\path
      arguments:
          kernel: "@kernel"
          doctrine: "@doctrine"
      tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

`Constructor of the new twig extension`

```
protected $kernel;
protected $doctrine;

public function __construct($kernel, $doctrine)
{
  $this->kernel   = $kernel;
  $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}
```

Write up some method:

```
/** @var string $repository. Example: AppBundle:Product' */
public function myEntity($repository)
{
  $manager = $this->doctrine->getManager();
  return $manager->getRepository($repository);
}
```

Register myEntity method in twig extension:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        'myEntity' =>  new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'myEntity'),

    );
}
```

Now in your twig templates you can access any repository:

`For example:`

```
{# 
    myEntity('SomeBundle:coolEntity').find()
    myEntity('SomeBundle:coolEntity').findAll()
    myEntity('SomeBundle:coolEntity').findBy()
    ...
#}
{% for item in myEntity('SomeBundle:coolEntity').findAll() %}
  {{ item.getId() }}
{% endfor %}
```